# x-debug causing false 'undefined property' errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

Has anybody else noticed this strange behaviour? I have php 5.6 with Xdebug 2.3.3 running on ubuntu 14.04. While debugging, within netbeans dev, I am being plagued with "undefined property" errors. Here's an example:

```
$bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
```

> Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder::$getParameter

As you can see, `getParameter` is a method, not a property. More often than not, this happens while hovering the mouse over a variable to look at its value, but it also happens if I leave the mouse in the code window for too long.

I have recently upgraded PHP to 5.6, mainly because PHPUnit requires it, and that is when the problems began.

Does anybody have any idea how I might be able to fix this? Or even which program (Xdebug, PHP, Netbeans) might be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My environment is the same as yours. As far as i can tell it is a problem with xdebug/php5.6 as on my container with php 5.4 this problem doesn't exist. I upgraded my xdebug to 2.4.0RC4(latest as of the writing of this post) and i can't reproduce it(needs further testing). You can try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only experiencing this. I'm staying away from php7 until it becomes mainstream, but I can try the newer version of xdebug.